# IOS native keyboard pushing entire webview up - cordova app

Tags: ios, angularjs, cordova

I am developing an app (IOS platform) using HTML5, CSS3, angular and cordova(3.8) and stuck with an major issue.

I have a page with footer having three buttons. On click of each button a modal comes up from the bottom. Modal position is set to fixed and inside it as scroll-able container. scroll-able container contains a text area where user can input some text.
Whenever the modal comes up, text area is focused so that keyboard comes up by default. The issue is whenever native keyboard comes up webview is pushed up and entire modal gets scrolled. 
I saw same issues been posted by others and I tried few solutions mentioned in reply for those questions like using ionic keyboard plugin, setting scrollTop to  0 on textarea focus. But nothing worked out.
In config.xml, I have set DisallowOverscroll to true.

It would be great helpful if someone help me with this issue ?

Comment: please confirm whether a window resize happening ?

Comment: No, window is not getting resized when keyboard comes up. Should I do the resize via javascript or it happens by default?

Comment: it will happen by default in most of cases, please register a resize event and check it